android testing app is not showing on play store
I have make 1 release version apk using Android Studio. Upload that on google play console and app review was complete and become publish. I don't like to make it public(app was shown on play store after search) now. so, I unpublished it. Now the problem is, after adding some new email on internal testing list new users can't found app using the link which i provide them.
and the message was,

Now my question is how can I resolve this issue by keeping app from public.
I want a solution to show app on internal testers play store and also need to hide app from play store so that other people don't access that.

share this link to registered testers, when testers click on link and they have to accept terms and conditions and verify. if they already accepted then wait approximate 10-20 min and refresh again.

i have edit my question. please check that

@Json Jack Make sure that you have to added your email in testers list and then try to open link and follow step as I mention in above comment.
